# Implementing unit of work in a WCF service with Autofac

Tags: wcf, autofac, unit-of-work

How can I implement unit of work pattern in a WCF service with Autofac?

Injecting the same instance per call (or in Autofac terms LifetimeScope) of the unit of work interface into my services and repositories is easy using Autofac's wcf integration - what I am after is a way to commit the unit of work changes on return of WCF service call obviously ONLY if there has not been any exceptions.

I have seen [Using a Custom Endpoint Behavior with WCF and Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989918/using-a-custom-endpoint-behavior-with-wcf-and-autofac) which is basically how I started out but that does not deal with exceptions.

Currently what I have is an `IOperationInvoker` that starts the unit of work in the Invoke and commits it only if there has not been any exceptions. The problem with this approach is that I need to resolve my unit of work instance inside the `Invoke` method which gives me a different instance than the one injected into my services and repositories using `AutofacInstanceProvider`.

Comment: Let's assume that we have registered a `IUnitOfWork` in the container. How can we wrap a service call with it and only call `SaveChanges()` if no exception have occurred? Or do we have to take the UoW in the service constructor?

Comment: When you say service call, do you mean WCF service call? If yes, then the link I have provided above shows how you can do that. The only problem is I have yet to find a way to only save the UoW if there has not been any exception when using AutoFac.

Comment: You said it yourself =) `what I am after is a way to commit the unit of work changes on return of WCF service call obviously ONLY if there has not been any exceptions.`. That's the hard part and what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Bradley Boveinis found a solution to this problem. We have not thoroughly tested it but it seems to work:

```
public class UnitOfWorkAwareOperationInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    private readonly IOperationInvoker _baseInvoker;

    public UnitOfWorkAwareOperationInvoker(IOperationInvoker baseInvoker)
    {
        _baseInvoker = baseInvoker;
    }

    public object[] AllocateInputs()
    {
        return _baseInvoker.AllocateInputs();
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        var result = _baseInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
        var context = OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Extensions.Find<AutofacInstanceContext>();

        try
        {
            context.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>().Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, string.Empty);
            new ElmahErrorHandler().ProvideFault(ex, null, ref message);
            throw;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return _baseInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state);
    }

    public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        return _baseInvoker.InvokeEnd(instance, out outputs, result);
    }

    public bool IsSynchronous
    {
        get { return _baseInvoker.IsSynchronous; }
    }
}
```

The key is in the following line:

```
OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Extensions.Find<AutofacInstanceContext>();
```

This grabs the UoW out of the ambient/current/contextual LifetimeScope.

Comment: Doesn't it commit the changes even if the operation throws an exception?

Comment: @jgauffin It shouldn't, as if there is an exception thrown within service call, it will be thrown at _baseInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs) call and all code below that will be ignored.